# running multiple commands using popen in c

Tags: c, linux, popen

Im creating a program using C that runs in a linux environment that needs to run multiple commands like this

**sudo -s**

**ls**

**pwd**

(assume that the commands under sudo -s are commands that needs to be super user to be able to run it)

Now, what I need to do is get all the output of these commands for further processing.
Here's the code

```
int executeCommand(char *command, char *result)
{
    /*This function runs a command./*/
    /*The return value is the output of command*/

    int nSuccess = -1;
    FILE * fp = NULL;
    char buffer[1035];

    if (command == NULL)
        render("Command is null");

    if (result == NULL)
        render("result is null");
    if (command!=NULL && result!=NULL)
    {
        fp=popen("sudo -s","w");
            fwrite ( " ls", 1, 3, fp);
            fwrite ( " pwd", 1, 4, fp);
        if(fp!=NULL)
        {
            strcpy(result,"\0");
            while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1,fp)!=NULL)
            {
                strcat(result,buffer);
            }
            pclose(fp);
        }   nSuccess=0;

    }

    return nSuccess;
}
```

The question is how will I be able to execute ls and pwd and then get it's output? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Formally speaking, there is no quesion in your post, but

1. if your problem is that `ls` and `pwd` are not executed by `sudo -s`:Try adding a newline to the `fwrite()`s (as you would type in your shell as well):

   ```
    fwrite ( "ls\n", 1, 3, fp);
    fwrite ( "pwd\n", 1, 4, fp);
   ```

   (a `" "` before the command shouldn't be neccessary)
2. Don't call `fwrite()` before checking `fp`
3. if you call `fp=popen("sudo -s","w");`, you can't use `fp` for reading. `while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1,fp)!=NULL)` won't work. If you want to pipe commands **to** `sudo` **and** want to read the output, you need two pipes what makes things a little more complicated, or maybe you can redirect `sudo`'s output to a temp file and read that afterwards:

   ```
   char tmpfile[L_tmpnam];
   char cmd[1024];
   tmpnam( tmpfile );
   sprintf( cmd, "sudo -s >%s", tmpfile );
   fp = popen( cmd, "w" );
   ....
   pclose(fp);

   FILE *ofp = fopen( tmpfile, "r" );
   if( rfp != null ) {
       while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1,rfp)!=NULL)
       {
           strcat(result,buffer);
       }
       fclose( rfp );
       remove( tmpfile );
   }
   ```

Comment: you said in no.2 to not call fwrite before checking fp, so how will I execute other commands aside from the first one? in no.3, simply, the mode 'r' means you can read the output of the command and mode 'w' means you can write to the output of first command BUT you have no option to read it? thanks

Comment: no.2: If `fp == NULL` starting `sudo` has failed, so there's no use in writing sth. to its stdin, but `fwrite()` might crash

Comment: no.3 there is indeed no option for `popen)()` like `"rw"` which allows you to both pipe data to a command's `stdin` and read its `stdout`

Comment: in that case, is there anyway to read from stdout? So that I can still get the output that I need?

Comment: In your case, redirecting `sudo`'s output and reding it afterwards might be the simplest solution. I've added som example code to my answer. Otherwise you need two pipes and have to call `fork()`, `exec..()` and `dup2()`. You will find examples in SO if you search for these commands